# FCM Notification Method is not called in background mode

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made one sample demo for Push Notification with FCM.
I am able to received Notification in Back Ground Mode as well as Foreground mode.
But my question is:-
When my application is in Background Mode Notification received but does not called any single Method so I can do action.

I agreed that when I have clicked on that method it will call one method but not in background.

## Method is i have used

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler { 

}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center  willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{

}
```

Please Help Me  guys I got stuck.I need it 
Thanks in Advance.
I have read so many links but not able to solved my Problem.

## Note:- Please keep in mind I have used Google clouding messaging:- FCM

I have used in Objective c

Comment: what is your notification payload?

Comment: did you add "content-available" : 1 in it?

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad: Sorry I am new in FCM where to put   content-available" : 1  ,Does it put at backend side ?

Comment: Pay Load Comes in this formate

{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}

Comment: your requirement is to call notification delegate on receiving a push before user interaction (user tap on notification banner) ??? is it?

Comment: Yes I have called Delegation method here it is:-[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;  In Didfinished launchingWith Option metho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727363/how-to-receive-ios-notifications-in-background-without-user-interaction/45728483#45728483

Comment: check this answer

Comment: @ M Zubair Shamshad  :Does  "content-available" : 1 added from back end side or i have to add in application side if yes then where in application code?

Comment: can be added at back-end side. (from where you are sending notification)

Comment: About payload see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) but yes just as Zubair said you must set `content-available` to `1` so your app would be awakened in backgrnd .Also related: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425744/alternative-to-usernotificationcenterdelegates-willpresent-when-app-is-in-backg/44705892#44705892) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)

Comment: Thanks I have Informed to backend person to add:- content-available :1

Comment: @hd1344 there are a few more things to make sure for this scenario to be handle. let me add as an answer

Comment: Did Not Called method even backend person add   "content-available" : 1

Comment: @hd1344 I have update the answer.

Comment: @hd1344  have you set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled type "Boolean" value "NO" in your info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion in comments under your question. Here are a few more things to be done to achieve your requirement. I m posting these points as you were not familiar with `content-available` thing.

Open your Xcode project and

1: In the Project Navigator, select your project.

2: In the editor, select your iOS app target.

3: Select the Capabilities tab.

4: Enable Push notification under capabilities.

[image]

5: Enable the Background Modes capability.

6: Enable the Remote notifications background mode.

[image]

Now if your notification payload contains `content-available : 1` then your app would be awakened in background.

The system delivers notifications by calling the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method of your app delegate. Use that method to initiate your desired operations.

Comment: Whatever things You have mentioned above I have  already implemented ,Just waiting for back end person for setting "content-available : 1" in his Pay Load Code.Thank You